# Weblate mark items as untranslated in the xliff-file?

Tags: translation, xliff, weblate

I have the following xliff-Translation-Format. And i need to mark Textitems as untranslated within the xliff-file, so that Weblate displays those as untranslated.

```
    <source>Delete</source>
    <note priority="1" from="description">Delete alert dialog</note>
    <note priority="1" from="meaning">Delete button label</note>
    <target state="needs-translation">Delete</target>
```

It seems that the state attributes aren't recognized by weblate. Only when the Target-Tag is empty, Weblate displays the item as untranslated. But the Target-Tag always needs to be not empty, since the application doesn't have a fallback and will display nothing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The [Weblate documentation](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/formats.html#xliff) is pretty clear that if a `<target>` element contains content, you can specify its state with the `state` attribute, e.g. with `new`, `needs-translation`, `needs-adaptation`, `needs-l10n`.

What you describe does not appear to conform to the above description. So after making sure the error is not on your end (you're using the correct XLIFF file and the latest Weblate version, you're not using any attributes on the `<trans-unit>` element that would conflict with the target status etc.), be sure to submit an [issue](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues).

In the meantime, you could experiment with the other status values listed above, maybe Weblate picks up those. Or you could try various upload options if they are available (the documentation mentions "Upload as translated" in passing).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Indeed we tried all the state-attributes with no luck at all. The only way to display untranslated items in Weblate was to empty the target tag.

Comment: Are you aware of the differences in Weblate between bilingual (=standard) and monolingual XLIFF? Did you check that the translations you enter in Weblate (for those trans-units that do show up) are correctly saved in the target element? I find it difficult to believe that this is an actual bug rather than just a configuration issue. But I don't know enough about Weblate to help you debug your configuration.

Comment: Other thing to note that the XLIFF states were not supported in Weblate prior to 3.3.

Comment: Thank you. I should update Weblate to the latest Version, currently i'm running 3.1.1.